# Diff value last two record by datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with `id, item_id, value (int), run (datetime)` and i need select *value diff* betwen last two *run* per *item_id*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT item_id, ABS(value1 - value2) AS diff
FROM (  SELECT h.item_id, h.value AS value1, h2.value AS value2
        FROM (  SELECT id, item_id, value
                FROM table_name
                GROUP BY item_id
                ORDER BY run DESC) AS h
        INNER JOIN (    SELECT id, item_id, value
                        FROM table_name
                        ORDER BY run DESC) AS h2
        ON h.item_id = h2.item_id AND h.id != h2.id
        GROUP BY item_id) AS h3
```

I believe this should do the trick for you. Just replace `table_name` to correct name.

**Explanation:**
Basicly I join the table with itself in a `run DESC` order, JOIN them based on item_id but also on id. Then I GROUP BY them again to remove potential 3rd and so on cases. Lastly I calculate the difference between them through ABS(value1 - value2).

Comment: Column name *datetime* does not exist. Did you mean *run* column? And sorry but i need diff between *value* (name) column not diff *run* column.

Comment: When using `GROUP BY` this way, can you count on it to return the first row of the group (where the notion of "first" comes from the orderings defined in the subqueries?)

Comment: tricky one that.. never knew about  ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in MySQL http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=36511. if this was MSSQL I would be using rownumber() over (partition by.. so i cant really complain about using platform specific stuff

Comment: Updated and used ABS() to always get a positive difference. @gordatron I've had this discussion multiple times, and I know from tests that it will get the value of the first sorted row :)

Comment: @RobinCastlin I like it, and it seems solid & MySQL docs say this is exactly how it behaves. like i say when it come to this kind of stuff I think its sometimes best to go with a platform specific solution

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT t2.id, t2.item_id, (t2.value- t1.value) valueDiff, t2.run
    FROM ( table_name AS t1 
           INNER JOIN 
           table_name AS t2 
           ON t1.run = (SELECT MAX(run) FROM table_name where run < t2.run) 
                 and t1.item_id = t2.item_id)
```

This is assuming you want the diff between a record and the record with the previous *run*